# Sharing Ehcache in multiple wars in weblogic 10.3 server

Tags: java, weblogic, ehcache

I want to share ehcache in multiple wars. I have put ehcache-core-2.2 jar in ear lib and its working fine in JBOSS. Same ear is not working in Weblogic 10.3. Caching is avaliable in the root context only, its not propgating to other web contexts. Any help in this regard would be highly appericiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an EAR file, placing the common JAR files in the `APP-INF/lib` directory and individual classes in the `APP-INF/classes` directory should work.

**Further Resources**

[Understanding WebLogic Server Application Classloading](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html)

Comment: I did place common jar files in APP-INF/lib but I also had entires of jar files in war MANIFEST.MF file, thats why it was not working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.